# SharePoint 2010 hangs on global nav change

Tags: navigation, site-settings

I have a SharePoint 2010 Enterprise deployment. When I attempt to modify the Global Navigation at the root site, it hangs for several seconds, then prompts for credentials, then gives me an unexpected error. Has anyone heard of anything like this before?

Update: Root Cause
After working with Microsoft, Davinci is the root cause.  Working with the vendor to resolve the issue.

Update: Stack Trace of slow running query.

> Slow Query StackTrace-Managed:     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OnPostExecuteCommand(SqlCommand
>   command, SqlQueryData monitoringData)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.MoveNavigationNode(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 lNodeId, DateTime dateParented, Int32 lParentId, Int32
>   lPreviousSiblingId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.MoveNavigationNode(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 lNodeId, DateTime dateParented, Int32 lParentId, Int32
>   lPreviousSiblingId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode.MoveInternal(SPNavigationNodeCollection
>   collection, Int32 iPreviousNodeId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode.UpdateSPNavigationNode(SPNavigationNode
>   node, SPNavigationNode previous, String name, String url, String
>   description, String target, String audience, Boolean forceCreate)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaNavigationSettingsPage.HandleJavaScriptNavigationNode(Guid
>   objId, Int32 nodeId, String name, String url, String description,
>   NodeTypes nodeType, String target, String audience,
>   SPNavigationNodeCollection collection, Dictionary`2 oldDictionary)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaNavigationSettingsPage.OKButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)      at
>   ASP._layouts_areanavigationsettings_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)      at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)

Comment: What does the ULS logs say? Can you find the logs and post them based on the correlation ID of the error?

Comment: I have been rerunning for the last 5 minutes waiting for it to fail.  WIll let you know when I have logs.

Comment: Do you have any custom solutions, like site templates deployed? Or do you have a large number of security settings on the subsites?

Comment: No custom solutions other than Axceler ControlPoint and Davinci.  No extensive permissions.